# Laravel having trouble displaying uploaded images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am attempting to create a simple file upload system for images, and even after hours of googling, I just can't seem to get it working. Users upload images to my website, I store the path of the image in the database, and then I show the images by making the database path the src of an img tag. Seems simple enough, but it still does not work for me. Anyway, here is my code.

```
//posting upload in controller
//i named images docs

public function postUpload(){

    Input::file('file')->move(base_path() . '/public/uploads');

    $doc = new Doc();
    $doc->title = Input::get('title');
    $doc->caption = Input::get('caption');
    $doc->path = base_path() . '/public/uploads' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

    $doc->save();

}
```

And here is my index view where I display uploaded images:

```
@extends('layouts.caselistlayout');

@section('content')


@foreach($docs as $doc)
<h1>{{ $doc->title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ $doc->caption}}</h2>
<img src='{{ $doc->path }}'>

@endforeach

@stop
```

I can provide the code for my upload view, but I don't think it is needed in this situation.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Forgot to mention that the exact problem is the images aren't displayed. The title and caption are displayed on the index page, but the image is not displayed. I only see the default HTML placeholder for where the image should be.

Edit 2: File ends up in the folder, and I can see the URL in the path column of the database.

Comment: Is there an error or does the file even end up in the folder?

Comment: I can see and view file in the public/uploads folder. I made an edit because I forgot to mention what the exact problem was.

Comment: I see, and can you see the URL ending up in the records?

Comment: Yes, the path is uploaded to the path column of the table.

Comment: Then change your question, because "the file indeed is uploading".

Comment: Will do, sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are saving full physical path to the database which is causing the issue. You actually need a `http` address. Example:

`http://example.com/uploads/img1.jpg`

Remove the following line:

```
  $doc->path = base_path() . '/public/uploads' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Instead, save the following:

```
  $doc->path = 'uploads/' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

and from your view:

`<img src='{{ asset($doc->path) }}'>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is still not working for me. I made the changes, but the image is still not showing. The image uploads to the database with the path of 'uploads/image.png.'Also, image.png exists in the public/uploads folder. The img tag simply does not display the picture.